# how to transfer values between threads using I/O streams?

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, posix

I have a thread that reads data from the console.
I want to write a test on it and the only thing I came up with is to declare another stream that will transmit melons through the I/O streams to the first stream, but I do not know how to do it, I want something like this:

```
void broadcast_func(void* arg){
 // run << broadcast
}
TEST_CASE("producer_routine test"){
  pthread_t broadcast;
  pthread_t run;
  if (pthread_create(&broadcast, nullptr, broadcast_func, nullptr) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (pthread_create(&run, nullptr, run_func, nullptr) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

can someone suggest?

P.S

```
int run_threads(void* arg){
    b_queue bq;
  // producer thread
  pthread_t p_thr;
  if (pthread_create(&p_thr, nullptr, producer_routine, (void*)&bq) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }
  pthread_detach(p_thr);
...
}
void* producer_routine(void* arg) {
  // read data, loop through each value and update the value, notify consumer,
  // wait for consumer to process
  b_queue* volatile bq = (b_queue*)arg;
  int64_t input;
  int64_t ch;
  while (std::cin >> input, ch = getchar(), (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)) {
    bq->add(input);
    //   std::cout <<"input: " << input << std::endl;
    if (bq->is_full()) {
      while (!bq->is_empty())
        ; 
    }
  }
  bq->q_done = true;
  return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Remember that thread scheduling is non-deterministic, so testing is less valuable.  Every test failure proves there is a problem, but test success in threaded code proves nothing.

Comment: C++ and `pthread_create`? Are you forced to use `C++03`?

Comment: Also this line `while (std::cin >> input, ch = getchar(), (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF))` looks very bad. What this code supposed to do? This indicates your understanding of streams and C++ is  still on basic level, so it is far to early for you to use threads (which introduce new kind of very subtle bugs).

Comment: This `b_queue* volatile bq = (b_queue*)arg;` is very bad too. This `volatile` doesn't provide any kind of synchronization!

Comment: @BenVoigt _so testing is less valuable_ I'm not sure I'd put it like that.  If you can contrive to put together a test that really hammers the code and you _do_ discover a problem, then you have obviously achieved something.  Still got to figure out what went wrong, of course...  Personally, I like to plaster the code with `assert`s, and then trap into the debugger if one fires.   At least then you might have something to work with.  But, more importantly, you have to be ultra careful when writing the code in the first place, because anything that can go wrong, will go wrong.  Eventually.

Comment: @PaulSanders: I think my comment adequately covered your point in the next sentence.  Anyway, best practice is to test the non-threaded helper functions that run inside each of the threads, but perform code inspection to verify correctness of the thread creation and synchronization.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair enough, you did say that.  I just didn't want the OP to conclude that it was pointless testing his code.  And that sounds like good advice, I hope you're still with us OP.  And _then_, once you believe that everything is bug-free, hammer the finished product as hard as you can, because it is notoriously difficult to write multi-threaded code correctly, especially if you don't have the experience.  Of course, maybe you don't actually _need_ to do that at all, none of us really knows from what you have told us.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you abstract I/O away through a mockable interface, with concrete implementation for production (using console I/O) and for testing (using some other mechanism, perhaps `stringstream` or something more custom).

Comment: I added a description. I know that std::thread is more convenient, but such a task

Comment: The abstraction already exists, as `std::istream&`

Comment: You're replying to the wrong person, I didn't mention `std::thread` at all. Also you had a stroke half way through.

Comment: @student213 What does _"I know std::thread is more convenient, but such a task"_ mean?

Comment: @user253751, I have nothing against that (though as a pointer, not a reference, so that virtual destructors all run as normal), but personally I believe that exposing streams like that is too low level of a detail to escape a function. If your purpose is to process a file, your function should, in my opinion, process the file (hopefully asynchroneously) and return (a promise to) the structured result, with the internal stream details never having leaked out.

Comment: Unless you mean as an input parameter of type `const istream&`, in which case I'm in complete agreement :)

Comment: @Blindy `std::istream&` is the normal way to pass a stream since they are not copyable. The thread is not going to destroy the standard input stream, either.